# Optional targets in Cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Is there a way to specify optional targets in CMake? I mean ones that are built only when one specifies them explicitly, for example by `make <target>`, and are not built when you specify just `make`? I know I can do this with add_custom_command(), but I need all the features that a normal build target has

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to use add_custom_target. You can simply specify EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL, when specifying the build rule for an executable via add_executable. The same applies to add_library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [add_custom_target()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) command.

Comment: add_custom_target() is always considered out of date, and I want proper dependency handling. THis is why I mentioned add_custom_command() in my initial post, however it does not know how to build sources like regular targets.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i didn't get right your question. Sure, @Martin answer is correct.